# unable to see state names in dropdown box using bootstrap formhelpers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using  [bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/gettingstarted/) to list down all state names into dropdown box.

Here is my _layout files references.

```
<!-- #region BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPT-->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-form-helper/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- #endregion -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
```

Here is my _InsuranceForm.cshtml partial view on which I have state dropdown box.

```
<div class="row top5">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3 label-small">
          State
     </label>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control bfh-states" name="State" data-country="US" id="cboInsuranceState"></select>
</div>
```

_InsuranceForm.cshtml partial view is being called into another partial view called: _Insurance.cshtml

Here is _Insurance.cshtml

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_InsuranceSummary");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_InsuranceForm");}
```

Now if I am adding following reference into _InsuranceForm.cshtml then it is working as expected

```
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap-form-helper/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
```

but since above reference is already exist into _Layout.cshtml file, so I want to add it into single place instead of two places because there are many other pages into my project which are using this reference to display state names into dropdown box.

Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can't you just remove the script from the partial view and leave the one in the layout?

Comment: @GigiSan Yes that's problem, if I will remove the script reference from the partial view and keep reference only in layout then it is not working.